# DataView filtering, clarification required on Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dataset and also taken a **string variable IsExModul** which is used during filter my code is as follows

```
string IsExModul ="Y" ;//By some condition this variable is set to Y
 ReportDataView = new DataView(FullReportData, "ReportSection = '" + ReportSection + "' and ( IsPentesterAccess = 'Y' or (" + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["isadmin"]) + " = 1 and IsAdminAccess = 'Y') or (" + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsSevTempAcess"]) + " = 1 and IsSevTempAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsWOModule"]) + " = 1 and IsWoModuleAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsExModule"]) + " = 2 and IsExceptionAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsExModule"]) + " IN (1,3)  and IsExceptionAccess = 'Y' and "+IsExModul+" = 'Y'  )   )"
```

Its Giving an exception 'Invalid Column name [Y]'
if i remove 'and "+IsExModul+" = 'Y'' from filter condition then it works fine,
why is it considering 'Y' as column.

Comment: You need the name of the column not the value 'Y' in the variable IsExModul

Comment: @Stev but IsExModul is a variable and i just need to check that IsExModul is Y

Comment: I dont understand why some one has downvoted this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the variable IsExModul from string to integer and now it is working fine as a filter in dataview

```
int IsExModul =1 ;//By some condition this variable is set to 1

ReportDataView = new DataView(FullReportData, "ReportSection = '" + ReportSection + "' and ( IsPentesterAccess = 'Y' or (" + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["isadmin"]) + " = 1 and IsAdminAccess = 'Y') or (" + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsSevTempAcess"]) + " = 1 and IsSevTempAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsWOModule"]) + " = 1 and IsWoModuleAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsExModule"]) + " = 2 and IsExceptionAccess = 'Y') or ( " + Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserInfo.Rows[0]["IsExModule"]) + " IN (1,3)  and IsExceptionAccess = 'Y' and " + IsExModul + " = 1   )   )", "SerialNumber", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

But still i am not clear why it does not work when it was of string datatype and set to 'Y'
,Can Someone help

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in your last part of the statement `and "+IsExModul+" = 'Y'  )   )`
This is expected to be some SQL text but IsExModul is not a column name where a value is supposed to be 'Y'

Comment: @ Bogoljub This is not a issue as i have now changed IsExModul to int datatype and it works fine, its just that it does not work when it is string datatype, may be there is some problem in single quotes or double quotes when datatype is string

Comment: hmm can you try to put it back to string and do this `'"+IsExModul+"' = 'Y'  ) ` just add a single quote before and after the double quotes respectively.